# Adding Count of Arrays Together returns 0

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following class, where the arrays are populated

```
public class InternalTag_RelatedObjectsViewModel
{
    public Guid[] BranchIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] CompanyIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] ContactIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] DivisionIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] TenderIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] ProjectIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] DocumentIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] NewsIDS { get; set; }
    public Guid[] PhotosIDS { get; set; }        

    public int Total
    {
        get
        {                               
            return (this.BranchIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.CompanyIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.ContactIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.DivisionIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.TenderIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.ProjectIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.DocumentIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.NewsIDS?.Count() ?? 0 + this.PhotosIDS?.Count() ?? 0);                
        }
    }
}
```

The class is populated and returned by the following method, on another class

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InternalTag_RelatedObjectsViewModel test = new InternalTag_RelatedObjectsViewModel()
        {
            CompanyIDS = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid() },
            NewsIDS = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() }
        };

        Console.Write(test.Total);
    }
```

But Total returns 0, Even when some of the arrays have data.
Am I missing something?

Comment: My bad typo it returns 0 always

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's much easier to help you when we can reproduce the problem. I suspect it's a precedence issue, but I'm having trouble reproducing it myself at the moment.

Comment: If you initialize your arrays may be it will start to return total count

Comment: It seems there is some difference between your code and pasted code or there is some other thread logic creates a new class or clears arrays.

Comment: Would be much easier if you put the breakpoint in return line, then check if the referenced arrays actually contains anything

Comment: HOW you initialized `InternalTag_RelatedObjectsViewModel` ???

Comment: `public int Total => (BranchIDS?.Length ?? 0) + (CompanyIDS?.Length ?? 0) +` and so on.

Comment: You should use ( ) around the ?? operator, that might solve the problem

Comment: Regardless of the actual cause, you  might consider obtaining the total in such a way that the repeating code is avoided, so debugging is easier in general (Not that it solves the actual problem in this case!). e.g. `return (new[]{BranchIDS, CompanyIDS, ContactIDS /*etc*/ }).Sum(a=> a?.Length ?? 0);`

Comment: @MongZhu: There *is* a problem, but you need to set it up so that there's a non-null array, followed by a null array, followed by a non-null array.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok after the edit, I see. Thanx for the clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing precedence, basically.

It's easier to see what's going on when this is reduced to a minimal example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] a = { "x", "y" };
        string[] b = { "x" };

        int first = a?.Length ?? 0 + b?.Length ?? 0;
        int second = (a?.Length ?? 0) + (b?.Length ?? 0);
        Console.WriteLine(first);   // Prints 2
        Console.WriteLine(second);  // Prints 3
    }
}
```

Obviously 3 is the right answer here. So what's going on?

The `??` operator has lower precedence than `+`, so `first` here is equivalent to:

```
int first = ((a?.Length ?? (0 + b?.Length)) ?? 0;
```

To split that up:

```
int? step1 = a?.Length;                // 2
int? step2 = step1 ?? (0 + b?.Length); // 2
int first = step2 ?? 0;
```

Note how because the result of step1 was non-null, we never end up taking the length of `b`.

You *want* to just apply the `??` operator on the result of each nullable length expression, so the brackets around `(a?.Length ?? 0)` do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

@VDN posted this answer and then removed it, but it fixed my problem.

Changing the way that Total is calculated to the following fixed my problem

```
    public int Total
    {
        get
        {                               
            return ((this.BranchIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.CompanyIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.ContactIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.DivisionIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.TenderIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.ProjectIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.DocumentIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.NewsIDS?.Count() ?? 0) + (this.PhotosIDS?.Count() ?? 0));                
        }
    }
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. If you could actually provide a [mcve], we could help to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Added the method as to how the class is populated

Comment: @JonSkeet, it seems necessary to add brackets, otherwise equation will only return length of first non null array. Perhaps due to `?.` operator ?

Comment: @Sinatr: Again, that's not what my tests showed, and we still don't have a [mcve].

Comment: @R2D2: That doesn't help. We can't copy, paste, compile, run, and see the difference. You should be able to do this in a very short console app.

Comment: @JonSkeet, for me - results [are different](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aI7Qgs) (tried in VS2015 too).

Comment: @Sinatr: Interesting - will investigate what the difference is between that and my tests. Thank you for coming up with a [mcve]. (Well, it's not quite minimal - I'm reducing it further at the moment...)

Comment: More simple example added, This now returns one, Seems that @Sinatr is right, It will return the length of the first non null array

Comment: @R2D2: Definitely better, although there's no need for a separate class here. Local variables (with simpler names, using strings or ints to populate easily) work just as well. I'll show an example in my answer.

Comment: @R2D2: Right, I've posted an answer with a full explanation.